# how to rewrite a function to recursive

Tags: python, recursion

I have this function in python. It works like map(func, l1, l2) when both lists have the same length. It applies a function to all the items in list1 and list2.

```
def map2(func, l1, l2):
   result = []
   if len(l1) > 0:
       for i in range(len(l1)):
          result.append(func(l1[i], l2[i]))
   return result
```

How can I rewrite it to recursive program?

Thanks

Comment: What is `func` ? please provide sample code with sample input and output data.

Comment: func can be any function that applies to all the items in list1 and list2. For example: lambda x,y: [x,y]

Comment: My program does the same as the python map function: map(function_to_apply, list_of_inputs) except the 2 lists must have the same length. For example: map2(lambda x,y: [x,y], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]), output is [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lengths of the lists to terminate the recursion.
In this example implementation, if length of either of the `list`s is 0, we have either mapped it all, or it is an empty `list` to begin with, thus we terminate the recursion. Also worth noting that `l1[1:]` is the slice of the `list` we haven't mapped yet.

```
def map3(func, l1, l2):
    if (len(l1) == 0 or len(l2) == 0):
        return []

    return [func(l1[0], l2[0])] + map3(func, l1[1:], l2[1:])
```

Let's test it:

Test function:

```
def func(a, b):
     return a * b
```

Test `list`s:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

Run it:

```
print(map3(func, l1, l2))
```

Output:

```
[4, 10, 18]
```